# Perform CRUD database operation from ios app and limiting the permission only to few user accounts

Tags: ios, user-permissions

Need help with a solution, i have to build a time table app and give access to only few users to be able to change and update time and i want to be able to trigger a remote notification to all app users for any changes in time table

Any ideas on how i can achieve this ?

Comment: There are many solutions you could pursue. I'd use CoreData as your back end. With CoreData, you can model and scale your data with objects and persistence is quick! It'll create an abstract interface where you can ultimately have a SQLite db backend or whatever! Use APN (Apple Push Notifications) for alerts and updated information. Creating user accounts, etc can be done with third parties or internally, it's up to you! You want to grant tokens, or use some secure method for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions you could pursue. I'd use CoreData as your back end. With CoreData, you can model and scale your data with objects and persistence is quick! It'll create an abstract interface where you can ultimately have a SQLite db backend or whatever!

Use APN (Apple Push Notifications) for alerts and updated information. Creating user accounts, etc can be done with third parties or internally, it's up to you! You want to grant tokens, or use some secure method for authentication.